# Execute shell script w/ arguments stored in another file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a Python script that requires me to set many flags.  I am trying to write some shell scripts to simplify the process of executing this Python script.

I would like to have two shell scripts, params.sh and run.sh.  In params.sh, I set the shell variables to the desired values like so:

```
VAR1=val1
VAR2=val2
...
```

In run.sh, I want to take the variables that I've set in params.sh, create a unique name from the values of each variable, and then use those variables as the flags to execute the Python script.  So in pseudocode, what I'd like to do is

```
PARAMS=get_params()
UNIQUE_NAME=make_unique_name(PARAMS)
python main.py --name=$UNIQUE_NAME --VAR1=${VAR1} --VAR2=${VAR2} ...
```

I'm stuck on how to create a shell function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments, and how I might process the list of params to execute the Python script as it appears in the last line of pseudocode.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would it be feasible to instead have a text file containing the parameters (`params.txt`) and pass the path to `params.txt` as the sole argument to the Python script? The Python script will then be responsible for parsing `params.txt` and creating the unique name.

Comment: Does `params.sh` have to actually be a shell script? Why can't it be basically the same format, but treated as a .cfg/.ini/whatever file? Then you can write a simple script (trivial in Python, for example) that reads a `params.cfg` file and prints a list of args, and all `run.sh` has to do is `python main.py --name=$UNIQUE_NAME $(python parse_cfg.py params.cfg)` or the like.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged Python? You're asking how to do something complicated with bash. You'd do the same thing to run a compiled program, or a perl script, or anything else. So why do you want Python experts rather than Bash experts to help you?

Comment: The [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module supports using files to store long lists of arguments, see [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars).

Comment: I am unfamiliar with bash, so forgive me.  The file containing the param values need not be a shell script.  And the suggested tags included Python.  I'll remove the tag.  Thank you kindly for your suggestions :)

Comment: If you need to support completely arbitrary arguments, best practice is NUL-delimited storage. Otherwise, corner cases around distinguishing literal newlines from syntactic ones &c. get... messy.

Comment: Anyhow, "how to create a shell function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments" -- where are you stuck? You don't need to declare a shell function's arguments *at all*, so there's nothing that enforces that the number that are used match some arbitrary count from anywhere else.

Comment: Also, **how much do you trust `params.sh`**? Are you willing to risk security vulnerabilities if it contains content that could be executed as code?

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) has much advice that's pertinent to your goal (of dynamically generating a shell command based on content only known at runtime).

Comment: I'm a complete beginner with bash and I'm not worried about security vulnerabilities.  Just trying to figure out bash scripts.  Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It's a good idea to learn robust practices early -- then you won't have to *re*learn later, when you're working somewhere security (or just reliability -- security bugs are *bugs*, after all, and can sometimes be triggered by random bad luck) is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read lines from file "vars", prefixing each with "--"
while IFS= read -r line; do
  args+=( "--$line" )
done <vars

# hash the contents of that variable
read -r _ unique_name _ < <(printf '%s\0' "${args[@]}" | openssl dgst -md5)

# use the hash as a name; then pass through the arguments
python main.py --name="$unique_name" "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: When I try this, the unique name appears to be empty.

Comment: Not sure why, but deleting the underscores around unique_name seemed to fix the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @Roflcakzorz, the underscores consume the first and third-and-later words of the input, leaving only the second. On my system, `openssl dgst -md5` omits output that looks like `(stdin)= b1946ac92...`, so the leading underscore is necessary to make sure that only the checksum, and not the `(stdin)=` at the front of the line, goes into the `unique_name` variable.

Comment: @Roflcakzorz, ...that said, I wonder if maybe your script sets a non-default value for `IFS`? That would explain why the splitting into words is happening on an undesired boundary. Or if you replaced `openssl dgst -md5` with `md5sum`, then we'd need to remove second-and-later, not first.